# Selenium WebDriver does not perform the required action although my Xpath is correct

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Selenium WebDriver does not perform the required action although my Xpath is correct:

```
public class Openchrome{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\DELL\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.amazon.in");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("Sri Raghavendra Swamy");
    driver.findElement(By.className("nav-input")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Sri Sadhguru Raghavendra Swamy Jeevitha Charitra')]")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@id='buybox-see-all-buying-choices-announce']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='buybox-see-all-buying-choices-announce']")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: [1574950086.902][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //a[@id='buybox-see-all-buying-choices-announce'] (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)

Comment: @Raghavendra Which action isn't performed? Which line? Update the question with the relevant HTML and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB, Thanks for the respone. I just recieved the below solution and it solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes right, all your locators are correct. Your issue comes from the following line:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Sri Sadhguru Raghavendra Swamy Jeevitha Charitra')]")).click();
```

After the above action, it will bring you to new tab. You need to switch first before to do something, so use `.getWindowHandles()` after perform the above line, like this:

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
//switch to second tab
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@id='buybox-see-all-buying-choices-announce']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='buybox-see-all-buying-choices-announce']")).click();
```

If you want to go back to the first tab again, just switch again with: `tabs.get(0)`.